# Cannot populate datatable from Arraylist in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable

I am trying to populate a datatable from an arraylist. After searching how to do it, i found out that i need to set value attribute to an arraylist in the jsf page. Here is the related part of my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "customer")
@SessionScoped
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private String identityNumber;
    private String password;

    private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

And my datatable definition in jsf page:

```
<h:form>
     <h:dataTable id="accountsTable" value="#{customer.accounts}"></h:dataTable>
```

The problem is, it gives an error saying "unknown property: accounts". It can see the identityNumber and password attributes but it cannot find accounts attribute. Can anyone tell me why and help me fix it?

Thanks

Edit: I solved the error but now the table is not populated. Here is the code:

```
<h:form>
        <h:dataTable id="accountsTable" value="#{customer.accounts}" var="account">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Account Number</f:facet>
                    #{account.accountNumber}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: You do have public getters and setters for `accounts` right?

Comment: oh i forgot to add them thanks, i will try it

Comment: @VikasV thanks that worked, if you want you can post an answer and i accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define getters and setters for your `accounts` list. As it appears from this error, `unknown property: accounts`, `accounts` is not available for display.

```
public List<Account> getAccounts()
{
        return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts)
{
        this.accounts = accounts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now there is not an error but table is not populated. I will edit the question can you please have a look at it again?

Comment: it looks like array looks empty. I will try to find how we can use session variables to populate datatable

Comment: Here is my new question if you have time you can have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503839/how-to-get-and-use-a-session-object-to-populate-a-datatable-in-jsf